# How to create a fixed header in bootstrap 4

Tags: html

I am trying to fix the header in top rather than fixed-top nav. How can I keep the header as fixed  while body part is scrolled. the section 'brand' and navbar should be kept fixed . Here is my code. Now when I scrolling the body part , the menu would be fixed , but the brand section would be scrolled . How can I keep the section part also fixed. I am using bootstrap 4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header id="header">
        <section class="brand">
            <div class="row bg-primary text-light pt-4">
                <div class="col-md-6 pl-5">
                    <p> sjkddjfhsdjdhfsddjkfh weuirrhweiueihruiwe weuirhuiweihruh wuierhiuweh rhweuirui sjkdfkhsdjkfh</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark bg-dark-header fixed-top" id="main-nav"
            style="margin-top: 60px;">

            <div class="container">
                <img src="img/Logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" style="width:250px;">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MyCompany</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Our Project</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position an element at the top of the viewport, from edge to edge. Be sure you understand the ramifications of fixed position in your project; you may need to add aditional CSS.

```
<div class="fixed-top">...</div>
```

this might help you as well:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/